# SMTP Debug com PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

gostaria de identificar um problema no seguinte código:

```
try {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $this->setLanguage("br");
    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $this->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $this->Host = 'hostname';
    $this->Port = 465;
    $this->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mail->setFrom('john@doe.com.br', 'John Doe');
    $mail->Subject = "Um e-mail qualquer";
    $mail->addAddress('fulano@gmail.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->body = "teste";

    $mail->send();

    $_SESSION['email_enviado'] = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['email_enviado'] = false;
    $_SESSION['descricao_erro'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Bom, esse e-mail não está sendo enviado, e eu não consigo visualizar o problema pois meu SMTP mesmo estando no level 4 não me retorna nada.

Gostaria de visualizar apenas o problema de acordo com o SMTP debug.

PS: Omiti por questões de segurança o username/password do host, da conta que o e-mail será enviado..

Comment: coloque $this->SMTPDebug = 1;

Comment: Não reproduzi seu problema, consigo visualizar os dados de Debug, no meu cenário utilizei seu código alterando somente $this->SMTPSecure para tls e  $this->Port  para 587.  Entretanto observei que $mail->body deve ser $mail->Body, se não o email não será enviado por falta de dados no corpo do email.

Comment: Era exatamente esse o problema.. Nossa.. E não recebia nenhum erro!!

Answer (score 5):

Para debugar no PHPMailer (versão 5 e 6), você precisa definir o atributo $SMTPDebug da instância do PHPMailer depois da instanciação assim:

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
...
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Ativar a saída do debug
...
```

É necessário atribuir ao atributo $SMTPDebug com uma das seguintes constantes (ou os valores inteiros entre parânteses):

```
SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0): Desativar o debug (você pode deixar sem preencher este valor, uma vez que esta opção é o padrão).
SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT (1): Imprimir mensagens enviadas pelo cliente.
SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER (2): similar ao 1, mais respostas recebidas dadas pelo servidor (esta é a opção mais usual).
SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION (3): similar ao 2, mais informações sobre a conexão inicial - este nível pode auxiliar na ajuda com falhas STARTTLS.
SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4): similar ao 3, mais informações de baixo nível, muito prolixo, não use para debugar SMTP, apenas em problemas de baixo nível.
```

**Observação:** apesar do erro do código ter sido encontrado por @oliveira ("$mail->body deve ser $mail->Body"), acredito que a resposta para a pergunta deveria ter sido completada. Por isso postei um adendo, uma vez que procurando por esta informação, caí nesta pergunta primeiramente.

Comment: Acho legal você completar a resposta (a idéia do site é essa, uma pergunta, várias respostas), dei +1 pois ela complementa com conhecimento extra. Vale notar que a resposta do Leandro já faz SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER  (o número 2 é exatamente isso) mas realmente é melhor usar as definições de fácil compreensão do que _magic numbers_

Comment: @Bacco concordo. Ele respondeu corretamente com o valor 2. Mas, resolvi colocar este complemento com as constantes e seus significados, pois era isso que estava procurando e caí aqui. Assim, se outros tiverem a mesma dúvida que eu, tem uma referência a mais. Ainda mais que na documentação oficial do PHPMailer não encontrei a referência para estas  constantes. Look: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_SMTPDebug

Comment: Vale sugerir ao pessoal do PHP mailer pra documentar (ou fazer um push, se os docs estiverem num repo também). Por ora, daria pra acrescentar um link pro source na resposta, onde tem as definições: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php

Answer (score 3):

```
Coloque $this->SMTPDebug = 2;
Após o send() coloque, die() ou exit() para interromper o fluxo e assim 
analisar a saída;

Quanto ao erro, usar $this->Body = "mensagem" ou $this->msgHTML("mensagem"), 
seu código faltou o conteúdo da mensagem.
```